# Initialize the value of each element of an array using a specific function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, element

Without creating a custom loop, is there an array function that allows us to initialize the value of each element of an array? For example, we have:

```
let myArray = new Array(8);
```

And we wanted to apply Math.random() for example against each element independently.

Comment: There is `fill` function but it's not working as you expect. You maybe can create a factory function that returns an array but it's gonna use loop again :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can achieve it this way:

```js
let myArray = Array.from({length: 8}).map((_, i) => {
  return Math.random();
});

console.log(myArray);
```

Now you can easily increase the length or initialize the array as you want in the return statement

**Edit**

Short one from @Nick Parsons

```js
let myArray = Array.from({length: 8}, Math.random);
console.log(myArray);
```

Comment: You can also use the mapping function of `Array.from()` to avoid the additional iteration with `.map()`. Eg: `Array.from({length: 8}, Math.random)`

Comment: @NickParsons That's exactly what I did and then I just precise the length of the array

Comment: I edited my comment to show an example of what I meant

Comment: Oh, powerful.  Thank you both.